# configure embedded tomcat context docBase and path in spring boot gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

How do I configure`<Context docBase="{C:/..}" path="{path}"/>` in spring boot gradle? i usually configure it in server.xml of external tomcat, how do I configure it via @Configuration file or in application.properties? Thank you.

Comment: what is the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may try use this:

```
tomcat.addWebapp("/path", "{C:/..}");
```

It is not exactly what addContent does, but might help you get your resources available under /path.